# Non-additive asymptotic upper density: $\mathsf{d}^\star(A\cup B) \neq \mathsf{d}^\star(A)+\mathsf{d}^\star(B)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\mathsf{d}^\star$ be the asymptotic upper density on $\mathbf{N}$, that is, for each $X\subseteq \mathbf{N}$ we have $\mathsf{d}^\star(X)=\limsup_n |X\cap [1,n]|/n$.

Then, is it possible to find a set $A$ of even numbers and a set $B$ of odd numbers such that
$$
\mathsf{d}^\star(A\cup B) \neq \mathsf{d}^\star(A)+\mathsf{d}^\star(B)?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $C$ of natural numbers whose binary representation has an odd length has upper asymptotic density $\frac{2}{3}$. The same happens for the set $D$ of natural numbers whose binary representation has an even length. In particular $d^\star(C)+d^\star(D)=\frac{4}{3}$ while $d^\star(C\cup D)=1$.

So, if we take $A=2C$ and $B=2D+1$, we have:
$$d^\star(A)=d^\star(B)=\frac{1}{3},\qquad d^\star(A\cup B)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: ...caro Jack :P